# Split String By Character

Tags: java, regex, string, split, character

I have a case in which I'm doing the following:

```
final String[] columns = row.split(delimiter.toString());
```

Where `delimiter` is a Character.

This works fine when I need to split based on tabs by providing `\t` as the delimiter. However, when I want to split on a pipe, I pass in a delimiter of `|` and this does not work as expected.

I've read several posts about how `|` is a special character which means null or empty therefore it splits on every character it encounters, though, I don't want this behavior.

I could do a simple check in my code for this pipe case and get around the issue:

```
if ("|".equals(delimiter.toString())) {
    columns = row.split("\\" + delimiter.toString());
}
else {
    columns = row.split(delimiter.toString());
}
```

But I didn't know if there was an easier way to get around this. Also, are there any other special characters that act like the `|` does that I need to take into account?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

...

final String[] columns = row.split(Pattern.quote(delimiter.toString()));
```

With regards to the other *metacharacters*, as they're called, here's a quote from the [String Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/literals.html) tutorial:

> This API also supports a number of special characters that affect the way a pattern is matched.
>
> ...
>
> The metacharacters supported by this API are: <([{\^-=$!|]})?*+.>

See:

- [`Pattern` class reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
- ["Methods of the Pattern Class" from *The Java Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pattern.html)

Answer (score 4):

1. You can use `StringUtils` from Apache Commons Lang which is equipped with methods accepting plain text, not regular expressions:

   ```
   public static String[] split(String str, char separatorChar)
   public static String[] split(String str, String separatorChars)
   ```
2. You can also use the `StringTokenzier` class, which does not expect a regular expression as the delimiter.